# Найти максимальное значение в потоке

Tags: java, потоки-данных

```
public class Run {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("Jean", "Clod-Van-Dame", 58));
    persons.add(new Person("Arnold", "Schwarzenegger", 72));
    persons.add(new Person("Silvester", "Stallone", 73));
    persons.add(new Person("Bruce", "Willis", 64));
    persons.add(new Person("Jackie", "Chan", 65));

    persons.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getFirstName().length() + p.getLastName().length() < 15)
            //??? getAge
            .map(p -> p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Всем привет. Подскажите, как из двух оставшихся объектов после первого фильтра(по длине имени): Bruce & Jackie, вывести один с наибольшим возрастом(Jackie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
persons.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getFirstName().length() + p.getLastName().length() < 15)
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge))
            .ifPresent(p -> System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName()));
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо)